# NodeJS mysql connection out of order

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I want to run a nodeJS server that accesses MySQL remotely. I have set up a connection, but then the query that I initiate does not finish (it runs async) before I attempt to display the data.

```
conpool.getConnection(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  conpool.query("SELECT * FROM orders", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
console.log("Checkpoint")
```

Outputs `Checkpoint` and then `[]`

I have read some questions on stack exchange and they seem to be using AJAX... They say some things about using callback functions, but it is all very confusing to me. Can someone please explain it relevant to my code, and in easy terms. I am coming from Python so I am not used to async problems at all.

I have also seen some things about `async/await` functions, and `promisify` stuff,  but I can't find simple documentation online for those.

My server is set up for testing, so I can easily test out any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you to read this [doc](https://javascript.info/promise-basics), also this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), Then feel free to ask something that you didn't understand...